# Designing argparse with many optional sub-arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I am currently writing a script for my library, and i ended up getting stuck on how to design argparse that will have a lot of options, and sub arguments.

Currently i am designing the search function, which has the following options, some required and some not:

- search_session_id - Required
- user_session_id - Required
- discover_fields - Optional
- start_time - Optional
- end_time - Optional
- summary_fields - Optional
- field_summary - Optional
- local_search - Optional

My problem is then the following:

How can i make the argparse and the if statements, if all optionals needs to work together, but also work if only one of them are defined?

If i need to check every single combination, i would end up with something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

"""Script to generate searches on the ArcSight Logger"""

import arcsightrest
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Script used to send search '
                                             'queries to ArcSight Logger API')
parser.add_argument('-t', '--target',
                    help='IP Address of the Loggger', required=True)
parser.add_argument('-u', '--username',
                    help='Username to access the logger', required=True)
parser.add_argument('-p', '--password',
                    help='Password to access the logger', required=True)
parser.add_argument('-ussl', '--unsecuressl', action='store_true',
                    help='Disable ssl warnings', )
parser.add_argument('-w', '--wait', action='store_true',
                    help='Wait for query to finish', )
parser.add_argument('-q', '--query',
                    help='Query to be used in the search')
parser.add_argument('-st', '--starttime',
                    help='From which time the query should look')
parser.add_argument('-et', '--endtime',
                    help='To which time the query should look')
parser.add_argument('-e', '--event',
                    help='Events based input search id')
parser.add_argument('-s', '--status',
                    help='Status of running search')
args = (parser.parse_args())

"""
Sets the target Logger Server
"""
arcsightrest.ArcsightLogger.TARGET = args.target

"""
Gets login token from the Logger API
"""
arc = arcsightrest.ArcsightLogger(args.username, args.password,
                                  args.unsecuressl)
"""
Checks if query is used, and starts a search
"""
if args.query:
    if args.starttime:
        search_id, response = arc.search(args.query, start_time=args.starttime,
                                         end_time=args.endtime)
    search_id, response = arc.search(args.query)

    if args.starttime and args.discover_fields:
        search_id, response = arc.search(args.query, start_time=args.starttime,
                                         end_time=args.endtime,
                                         discover_fields=args.discover_fields)
    print('The search id is {}'.format(search_id))
    if response:
        print('The search has successfully started')
```

As you can see, i can continue with no end, to make if statements that have every single combination of optional arguments. There must be an easier way to design this? If i was to just parse it in as kwargs, they would not be sent in the correct format, or i would require the person using the script to write things like `end_time=SOMETIME`, instead of just `--endtime TIME`. Now this might seem to be a small price to pay, but if i need to add every function with all their parameters into the script, then this will be come a lot longer and more tedious.

Comment: What about subcommands? https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/argparse.html#sub-commands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could collect all the optional keyword arguments passed to `arc.search` to a `dict` and then unpack it when you call the function:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Script used to send search '
                                             'queries to ArcSight Logger API')
parser.add_argument('-t', '--target',
                    help='IP Address of the Loggger', required=True)
parser.add_argument('-u', '--username',
                    help='Username to access the logger', required=True)
parser.add_argument('-p', '--password',
                    help='Password to access the logger', required=True)
parser.add_argument('-q', '--query',
                    help='Query to be used in the search')
parser.add_argument('-st', '--starttime',
                    help='From which time the query should look')
parser.add_argument('-et', '--endtime',
                    help='To which time the query should look')
args = (parser.parse_args())

# Mock search
def search(query, start_time=None, end_time=None, discover_fields=None):
    return 'Id', ', '.join(str(x) for x in [start_time, end_time, discover_fields])

"""
Checks if query is used, and starts a search
"""
if args.query:
    # {name used in argparse: search parameter name}
    query_args = {
        'starttime': 'start_time',
        'endtime': 'end_time',
        'discover_fields': 'discover_fields'
    }
    d = vars(args)
    real_args = {v: d[k] for k, v in query_args.items() if k in d}
    search_id, response = search(args.query, **real_args)

    print('The search id is {}'.format(search_id))
    print('Response is {}'.format(response))
```

Output:

```
>python test.py -t foo -u user -p pass -q
query -st start -et end
The search id is Id
Response is start, end, None
```

Since some of the argument names used by parser are different than the ones passed to `search` the names need to remapped. [`vars`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars) is used to create a `dict` from [`Namespace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.Namespace) object returned by `parse_args()`. Then dictionary comprehension iterates over the mapped argument names, picks ones which were given user and creates a new dictionary with key names that `arc.search` understands. Finally `**real_args` unpacks the dictionary named parameters within the function call.